# Hyperledger configtxgen creates genesis.block without Application Group

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Whenever I try to connect a peer to a channel I receive the following error message :

> Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: "JoinChain" for chainID = productionChannel failed because of validation of configuration block, because of Invalid configuration block, missing Application configuration group))

I’ve noticed that when I have done the example setups, the genesis block has a section for Application. However, with my current setup, the genesis block does not contain the Application section. Is there a way to instantiate the genesis block with the application embedded or another way to join the peer to the channel?

My configtx.yaml is below :

```
Profiles:

OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *TestOrg
OneOrgChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *TestOrg

Organizations:
- &OrdererOrg
    Name: OrdererMSP
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/test-com/msp

- &TestOrg
    Name: TestOrgMSP
    ID: TestOrgMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/testorg-test-com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0-testorg-test-com
          Port: 7051

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
OrdererType: solo
Addresses:
    - orderer-test-com:7050
BatchTimeout: 2s
BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
Kafka:
    Brokers:
        - 127.0.0.1:9092

Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one else runs into this issue, here is what is happening.
I was mistakenly trying to join the peers to the genesis block. The genesis block should not have an application section in it, as it is the system channel. This is created either through using the configtxgen tool from Fabric, or having the Orderer produce it when it is first created.

Then you need to create another channel block, using configtxgen or through CLI `peer channel create` . Then you can issue a `peer channel join` command using the -b flag for the path of the block.